# Localstorage arrays to be saved in Database using Django

Tags: jquery, django, modal-dialog, local-storage

I am having problems with a certain code. I'm still new to Django and Jquery.

So I have a form, and all the fields are stored directly in the database using the views.py in and I'm using self.request.POST['var']
for each element that I'm saving in the back end. 
It works, but
my problem is, how can I store multiple arrays from local storage. Since, I'm also working with a modal where I'll enter certain values. The values are stored in an itemlist and publishes a table row, for each time I click add, in the modal.

I want to get all those items/elements and save it in the database.

I've tried to use the self.request.POST but i keep on getting an error like MultipleInvalid entry. I'll send my code here, thanks

The code is below. 
Also i'm getting the results of the localstorage like this.

I want to get all the modal element and since Print itemdata just gives the values of the localstorage, I want to store the value of the localstorage each. 
I'm getting the itemdata like this.

[{"invitem_id":"85","invitem_code":"01086","invitem_desc":"1/2 PROGRAMMING FOR PONGRASS PONENTRY","charging_type":"R","unitofmeasure_id":"33","unitofmeasure_code":"OT","quantity":"1"
,"discountamount":"1","discountrate":"","unitcost":"1231.00","grossamount":"1231.00","netamount":"1231.00","vatable":"0","vatexempt":"1231.00","vatzerorated":"0","vatamount":"0.00","
branch_id":"5","branch_code":"HO","department":"34","department_code":"CCI","employee_id":"647","employee_code":"010019700","employee_name":"MARIA DORIS ABADILLA","remarks":"12312312
"}]

I want to store these values in the database, per element and I'm having difficulty in removing or changing them.
I've tried self.object.POST['invitem_id'], and usually the rest. it says that 'unicode' object has no attribute 'get' when I try to retrieve all of this.

Comment: You need to actually show the code.

Comment: are you using django forms else simply creating your own form in HTML ?

Answer (score 1):

```
    <input type="hidden" id="itemdata" name="itemdata">
  <div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
     <div class="modal-content">

       <div class="modal-header no-border">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
              <h4 class="modal-title text-center" id="addtitle">Add Items for Purchase Order</h4>
                    <h4 class="modal-title text-center"id="edittitle">Edit 
 Items for Purchase Order</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <input type="hidden" id="itemidentifier">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                    <label class="col-form-label-sm">Item</label>
                        <select id="invitem_name"  name="invitem_name" class="form-control form-control-sm select2" style="width: 100%">
                            <option value="">--- Select Item Here---</option>
                            {% for invitem in invitem %}
                            <option value="{{ invitem.id }}" data-unit="{{ invitem.unitofmeasure_id }}" data-cost="{{ invitem.unitcost }}" data-code="{{ invitem.code }}" data-desc="{{ invitem.description }}">{{ invitem.code }} - {{ invitem.description }}</option>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </select></select>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">

                <label class="col-form-label-sm">Charging Types</label>
                    <select id="charging_type" name="charging_type" 
class="form-control form-control-sm" required>
                        <option value="R">Regular</option>
                        <option value="P">Personal</option>
                        <option value="C">Company</option>
                        <option value="A">Advances</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

            </div>


            <div class="row">

                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <label class="col-form-label-sm">Unit</label>
                    <select id="unitofmeasure_id" name="unitofmeasure" class="form-control form-control-sm" required>
                        <option value="">---Select Unit---</option>
                        {% for unitofmeasure in unitofmeasure %}
                        <option value="{{ unitofmeasure.id }}" data-code="{{ unitofmeasure.code }}" {% if form.unitofmeasure.value|add:0 == unitofmeasure.id %} selected="selected" {% endif %}>{{ unitofmeasure.description }}&nbsp;</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <label class="col-form-label-sm">Quantity</label>
                        <input type="number" step="any" id="quantity" name="quantity" onkeyup="computeValue()" class="form-control text-right form-control-sm" required>
                        </input>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">

                    <label class="col-form-label-sm">Discount</label>
                    <input type="number" step="any" name="discountamount" id="discountamount" class="form-control text-right form-control-sm" required>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">

                    <label class="col-form-label-sm">Discount Rate</label>
                    <select id="discountrate" name="discountrate" class="form-control form-control-sm" required>
                        <option value="">Select Discount</option>
                        <option value="1">%</option>
                        <option value="2">amt</option>
                    </select>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class ="row">

                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label class="col-form-label-sm">Unit Cost</label>
                    <input type="number" step="any" id="unitcost" name="unitcost" onkeyup="computeValue()" class="form-control text-right form-control-sm" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label class="col-form-label-sm">Gross Amount</label>
                    <input type="number" step="any" id="grossamount" name="grossamount" class="form-control text-right form-control-sm" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label class="col-form-label-sm">Net Amount</label>
                    <input type="number" step="any" id="netamount" name="netamount" class="form-control text-right form-control-sm" required>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class = "row">

                <div class="form-group col-md-3">

                    <label class="col-form-label-sm">VATable</label>
                    <input type="number" step="any" name="vatable" id="vatable" class="form-control text-right form-control-sm"  required>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">

                    <label class="col-form-label-sm">VAT Exempt</label>
                    <input type="number" step="any" name="vatexempt" id="vatexempt" class="form-control text-right form-control-sm" required>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">

                    <label class="col-form-label-sm">VAT Zero Rated</label>
                    <input type="number" step="any" name="vatzerorated" id="vatzerorated" class="form-control text-right form-control-sm" required>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">

                    <label class="col-form-label-sm">VAT Amount</label>
                    <input type="number" step="any" name="vatamount" id="vatamount" class="form-control text-right form-control-sm" required>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="row">

                <div class="form-group col-md-3">

                <label class="col-form-label-sm">Branch</label>

                    <select id="branch_id" name="branch" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                        <option value="">--- Select Branch ---</option>
                        {% for branch in branch %}
                        <option value="{{ branch.id }}" data-code="{{ branch.code }}" {% if branch.code == 'HO' %} selected="selected" {% endif %}>{{ branch.description }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>

                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-md-4">

                <label class="col-form-label-sm">Department</label>
                    <select id="department_id" name="department" class="form-control form-control-sm" style="width:100%">
                        <option value ="" selected="selected">--- Select Department ---</option>
                        {% for department in department %}
                        <option value="{{ department.id }}" data-code="{{ department.code }}">{{ department.code }} - {{ department.departmentname }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>

                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-md-5">

                    <label class="col-form-label-sm">Employee</label>
                    <select id="employee_id" name="employee" class="form-control form-control-sm select2" style="width: 100%">
                        <option value="" selected="selected">------- Employee Name -------</option>
                        {% for employee in employee %}
                        <option value="{{ employee.id }}" data-code="{{ employee.code }}" data-name="{{ employee.firstname }} {{ employee.lastname }}"> {{ employee.code }} - {{ employee.lastname }}, {{ employee.firstname }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </select>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="row">

                <div class= "form-group col-md-12">

                        <label class="col-form-label-sm">Remarks</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control form-control-sm" id="remarks" style="height: 80px;" name="remarks" required></textarea>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">

            <div class= "form-group col-md-6">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">

                <button type="button" id="save_item" class="btn btn-primary">Save Item </button>
                <button type="button" id="update_item" class="btn btn-success">Update Item</button>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">

                <button type="button" id="close_item" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"> Close </button>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

JQuery code for getting the value of the modals. and Storing to Localstorage.

```
$('#save_item').click(function () {

    var validate = validateItems();

    if (validate == false) {
        return false;
    }

    var oldItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("dataObject")) || [];

    var newItem =
    {
        'invitem_id': $('#invitem_name').val(),
        'invitem_code': $('#invitem_name').find(':selected').attr('data-code'),
        'invitem_desc': $('#invitem_name').find(':selected').attr('data-desc'),
        'charging_type'   : $('#charging_type').val(),
        'unitofmeasure_id': $('#unitofmeasure_id').val(),
        'unitofmeasure_code': $('#unitofmeasure_id').find(':selected').attr('data-code'),
        'quantity'  : $('#quantity').val(),
        'discountamount' : $('#discountamount').val(),
        'discountrate': $('#discountrate').val(),
        'unitcost'   : $('#unitcost').val(),
        'grossamount'   : $('#grossamount').val(),
        'netamount'   : $('#netamount').val(),
        'vatable'   : $('#vatable').val(),
        'vatexempt'   : $('#vatexempt').val(),
        'vatzerorated' : $('#vatzerorated').val(),
        'vatamount'   : $('#vatamount').val(),
        'branch_id': $('#branch_id').val(),
        'branch_code': $('#branch_id').find(':selected').attr('data-code'),
        'department': $('#department_id').val(),
        'department_code': $('#department_id').find(':selected').attr('data-code'),
        'employee_id': $('#employee_id').val(),
        'employee_code': $('#employee_id').find(':selected').attr('data-code'),
        'employee_name': $('#employee_id').find(':selected').attr('data-name'),
        'remarks': $('#remarks').val()
    };



    oldItems.push(newItem);

    localStorage.setItem('dataObject', JSON.stringify(oldItems));
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
```

}
}

Python code for getting the itemdata (localstorage value, which is either list or dictionary), i need to make use self.request.POST for each entries.

```
def form_valid(self, form):


    self.object = form.save(commit=False)

    itemdata = self.request.POST['itemdata']

    print itemdata



    self.object.enterby = self.request.user
    self.object.modifyby = self.request.user
    self.object.save()
```